# How to do SQL Server transactions with Python through SQLAlchemy without blocking access to db tables in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, transactions

I've been stuck for a while now on this question and wasn't able to find the right answer/topic on the internet.

Basically, I have a table on SQL Server that I try to 'replace' with an updated one in a pandas dataframe form. I need to do a transaction for this task so that my original table isn't lost if something goes wrong while transferring data from dataframe (*rollback* functionality). I found a solution for this - SQLAlchemy library.
My code for this:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://server_name:password@user/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df.to_sql(name = 'table_name', schema = 'db_schema', con = conn, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
```

The problem occurs when I try to access the tables in this specific database through SQL Server Management Studio 18 while doing this transaction because it somehow manages to block the whole database and no one can access any tables in it (access time limits exceeded). The code above works great, I've tried to transfer a small chunk of dataframe, but the problem still persists, because I need to transfer a large dataframe.

What I've tried:

1. The concept of isolation levels, but this isn't the right thing as it's about the rules of connecting to a table that is already being used.
   Example:

   `engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://server_name:password@user/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0", isolation_level="SERIALIZABLE")`
2. Adjusting such parameters as **pool_size** and **max_overflow** in *create_engine()* statement and **chunksize** in *df.to_sql()* statement but they don't seem to have an effect. Example:

   `engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://server_name:password@user/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0", pool_size = 1, max_overflow = 0)`

   `with engine.begin() as conn: df.to_sql(name = 'table_name', schema = 'db_schema', con = conn, if_exists = 'replace', chunksize = 1, index = False)`
3. Excluding *schema* parameter from *df.to_sql()* query doesn't work either

Basic SQL code and functionality I'm trying to achieve for this task would look something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   BEGIN TRY
   
         DELETE FROM [db].[schema].[table];
         INSERT INTO [db].[schema].[table] <--- dataframe
         COMMIT TRANSACTION
   
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH

         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS [Error_number], ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [Error_description]

   END CATCH
```

I could create another buffer table and parse df data into it and do a transaction of this table afterwards, but I'm looking for a solution to bypass these steps.

If there is a better way to do this task please let me know as well.

Comment: `if_exists="replace"` will drop the table and re-create it before inserting the rows. You might try testing if the table exists, and if it does then do a `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name`, then do `to_sql(…, if_exists="append")`. The (implicit) `DROP TABLE` for `if_exists="replace"` may be messing you up.

Comment: Note also that SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation is the most restrictive and therefore the most likely to lock out other sessions. You might want to look into SNAPSHOT transaction isolation as an alternative.

Comment: @GordThompson, if I use `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` outside of transaction initiated by `to_sql()` wouldn't I lose rollback functionality? Because as I understand it we would clear the table before transacting to it and data will be lost if something happens.

Comment: You can create your own transaction using a `with engine.begin() as conn:` block, inside of which you would do `conn.exec_driver_sql("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name")` followed by `df.to_sql("table_name", conn, if_exists="append", …)`. Unless there is some limitation of TRUNCATE TABLE w.r.t. transactions the whole thing should be rolled back if there is an error.

Comment: @GordThompson, ahh, got it, I'll give it a try, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @GordThompson, the right solution considering that your db table already exists  is as follows:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://server_name:password@user/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")
# start transaction
with engine.begin() as conn:
    # clean the table
    conn.exec_driver_sql("TRUNCATE TABLE [db].[schema].[table]")
    # append data from df
    df.to_sql(name = 'table_name', schema = 'schema_name', con = conn, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```